# How to display MySQL table data which is stored as an array?

Tags: php, mysql, array

I have the table "mlw_results" which stores results of quizzes on my WordPress website. I use "Quiz And Survey Master" plugin to create these quizzes.
Now I need to display all the results of a particular quiz session (Result Id=7).

Though I get all other fields as required, two Arrays are displayed where I want the real values instead of arrays.

```
<?php
define( 'SHORTINIT', true ); 
require( 'wp-load.php' );
$id=7;
global $wpdb;
$result_data = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}mlw_results WHERE result_id = {$id}", ARRAY_A);
        $quiz_result = unserialize($result_data['quiz_results']);
        $response_data = array(
            'quiz_id' => $result_data['quiz_id'],
            'quiz_name' => $result_data['quiz_name'],
            'quiz_system' => $result_data['quiz_system'],
            'quiz_payment_id' => '',
            'user_ip' => $result_data['user_ip'],
            'user_name' => $result_data['name'],
            'user_business' => $result_data['business'],
            'user_email' => $result_data['email'],
            'user_phone' => $result_data['phone'],
            'user_id' => $result_data['user'],
            'timer' => 0,
            'time_taken' => $result_data['time_taken'],
            'contact' => $quiz_result['contact'],
            'total_points' => $result_data['point_score'],
            'total_score' => $result_data['correct_score'],
            'total_correct' => $result_data['correct'],
            'total_questions' => $result_data['total'],
            'question_answers_array' => $quiz_result[1],
            'comments' => ''
        );
        foreach($response_data as $value=> $quiz_result[1]){
        echo $quiz_result[1]."<br>";}
?>
```

The result I get is:

```
1
New Quiz
0

137.97.167.96
John
Webmaster
me@mypersonalmail.com
998121
1
0

02:09:32 PM 04/08/2020
Array

1
50
1
2

Array
```

I would like to replace those arrays with real values. Is it possible?
The data stored in the column "quiz_results" is as follows:

> a:5:{i:0;i:89;i:1;a:2:{i:0;a:9:{i:0;s:17:"Capital of
>   Kerala";i:1;s:9:"Trivandum";i:2;s:9:"Trivandum";i:3;s:0:"";s:7:"correct";s:7:"correct";s:2:"id";s:1:"1";s:6:"points";d:1;s:8:"category";s:0:"";s:13:"question_type";s:1:"0";}i:1;a:9:{i:0;s:20:"Capital
>   of Karnataka";i:1;s:13:"None of
>   these";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";s:7:"correct";s:9:"incorrect";s:2:"id";s:1:"2";s:6:"points";d:0;s:8:"category";s:0:"";s:13:"question_type";s:1:"0";}}i:2;s:0:"";s:7:"contact";a:4:{i:0;a:3:{s:5:"label";s:9:"Your
>   Name";s:5:"value";s:4:"John";s:3:"use";s:4:"name";}i:1;a:3:{s:5:"label";s:10:"Your
>   Email";s:5:"value";s:21:"me@mypersonalmail.com";s:3:"use";s:5:"email";}i:2;a:3:{s:5:"label";s:13:"Your
>   Business";s:5:"value";s:9:"Webmaster";s:3:"use";s:4:"comp";}i:3;a:3:{s:5:"label";s:10:"Your
>   Phone";s:5:"value";s:6:"998121";s:3:"use";s:5:"phone";}}s:8:"timer_ms";i:89634;}

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to replace those arrays with real values. Is it possible?

I am assuming you want to access and print those two variables which is shown as "Array" in the print out (contact, question_answers_array)

Solution as follows - replace your foreach look with below (I didn't test code but should give you an idea):

```
foreach($response_data as $key=> $value){
    if($key=='contact'){
        echo 'contact array:<br>';
        $value = unserialize($value); //turn serialized string into array
        print_r($value)."<br>"; //prints out the array all at once for debug
        //if you want to loop through
        foreach($value as $contactKey=>$contactValue){
                echo $contactKey."<br>";
                echo $contactValue['label']."<br>";
                echo $contactValue['value']."<br>";
                echo $contactValue['use']."<br>";
        }
    }elseif($key=='question_answers_array'){
        echo 'question_answers_array:<br>';
        $value = unserialize($value);
        print_r($value)."<br>"; 
        //if you want to loop through
        foreach($value as $qKey=>$qValue){
                echo $qKey."<br>";
                echo $qValue['0']."<br>";
                echo $qValue['1']."<br>";
                echo $qValue['2']."<br>";
                echo $qValue['3']."<br>";
                echo $qValue['correct']."<br>";
                //so on....
        }
    }else{
        echo $value."<br>";
    }
}
```

Give it a try; may have to fix some syntax / code issues.